# AttributeError: 'decode' when reading TIFF images

Tags: python, tensorflow, tiff, sys

Here is part of the code I am attempting to run:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import imageio
import sys
    #Create tensorflowflow dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((image_paths, labels))

    if not is_test:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(num_of_samples)
        dataset = dataset.repeat(None)

    dataset = dataset.map(self._parse_dataset)

    if not is_test:
        batched_dataset = dataset.batch(self.batch_size, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(20)
    else:
        batched_dataset = dataset.batch(self.test_batch_size)
    #Create the iterator
    return batched_dataset, num_of_samples, path_strings

def get_batch(self, subset="train"):
    batch_of_images = self.iterators[subset].get_next()
    return batch_of_images

def _read_tif(self, file_path):
    file_path = file_path.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())
    try :
        im = imageio.imread(file_path)
    except:
         im = np.zeros((self.width, self.height, 3))
    if len(im.shape) != 3:
        im = np.repeat(im[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
    return im

def _read_image(self, file_path):
    return tf.py_function(func=self._read_tif, inp=[file_path], Tout=tf.uint8)
```

and I have the following error coming up:

```
File "C:\PROJECTS_RUNNING2\pipeline\data_loader\data_generator.py", line 131, in _read_tif
    file_path = file_path.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())

AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

The file_path is defined in the run.py and looks like this:

```
def main(config_file_path):

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
config =tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
tf.reset_default_graph()

config = parse_config_file(config_file_path)

#Create the experiment output folders, this is where the outputs will be saved
output_folder_path = config["output_path"]
output_path = create_output_folder(output_folder_path,  config["experiment_name"])
copyfile(config_file_path, os.path.join(output_path, "%s_parameters.json"       % config["experiment_name"]))

data_generator = DataGenerator(config)
```

Input and Output dataset file paths are correctly defined in the config file.

I a very much beginner in coding though have to use the script for analysis of my images and I am struggling to get it up and running. Im using Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 1.14. Any help to resolve this error will be really much appreciated!

Comment: the error seems to be caused by using `file_path` incorrectly; I don't see that variable being defined anywhere in the code you posted. Could you please check where `file_path` is set?

Comment: Thanks MrFuppes for your answer, the file_path is defined in the run.py file as shown in the edited post. Any ideas where it is going wrong?

Comment: If you have a look at the error message, it tells you that `file_path` is a 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object. From the code however, you can deduce that it should be bytes as you call `file_path.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())` ([docs on decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)). So something is going wrong here with the definition of file_path but it is very hard to tell where...